# Windows 10 people contact list won't update

Tags: windows-10-mobile, insider-preview, sync, contacts

I have now got Windows platforms for all devices (nice idea I thought)
however I have now spent a lot of time sorting the people list in my PC "people" list.
I thought it would automatically update my contact list on my phone, but it hasn't

Any thoughts on how I can have my phone adopt the updated contact list from my Windows PC "people" lists?

Comment: what do you mean by "sorting"?

Comment: Also, what version of the OS is the phone running?

Comment: Go to https://people.live.com and check if the changes you've made are visible there. This should help narrow the issue down to either your PC or your phone.

Answer (score 2):

The contact list should automatically be updated in every OS version. If this doesn't happen check that:

1. You have internet connection on all devices and have updated the contacts list or gave enough time for the sync to happen
2. You try from the same OS version. Although this shouldn't matter, I have had cases where the win 10 PC app didn't update the win 8.1 phone or same when using the web app.
3. You use the same account on the devices.
4. You have the social integration linked to your account and the according apps installed on each device. For example the facebook, twitter etc apps installed and using synced contacts from the settings
5. You may already have the contacts synced but individually by service. In win 10 the linked contacts do not always carry over due to a new limitation presented by the facebook api and you need to link them again manually. They are there but not together.
6. Reset your phone. The most extreme and last solution to try but I doubt you will reach to this one without resolving your issue